# Databind a List<System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image> to a repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net

Im trying to bind a List of Images (`System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image`) to a repeater, but the image is shown as broken. It seems allright when I put a breakpoint inside the ItemDataBound-event, the DataItem is correct and have the correct ImageUrl. Yet, the result is wrong.

This code is very simple, but will be way more complex at the end. Binding a `List<String>` with ImageUrls wont help me in the end, since all images will have more unique properties aswell.

Repeater:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repButtons" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="repButtons_OnItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Image ID="imgButton" runat="server" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Making the list with images:

```
List<System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image> myButtons = new List<System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image>();

Image myEditButton = new Image();
myEditButton.ImageUrl = "~/images/themes/pencil.png";

myButtons.Add(myEditButton);

repButtons.DataSource = myButtons;
repButtons.DataBind();
```

Databinding:

```
protected void repButtons_OnItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        Image myImage = (Image)e.Item.DataItem;

        Image imgButton = (Image)e.Item.FindControl("imgButton");

        imgButton = myImage;
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe a bug on this (last) line `imgButton.ImageUrl = myImage;` and the Image Button is not an image that you assign to it.

Comment: What if you just change `imgButton = myImage;` to `imgButton.ImageUrl = myImage.ImageUrl;` ?

Comment: `imgButton.ImageUrl = myImage.ImageUrl;` Makes the image show, but the image will have more complex properties than that

Comment: What if you change your `<asp:Image>` to a `<asp:PlaceHolder>` then in the DataBound event, just add the control to the placeholder?

Comment: Adding the Image to a PlaceHolder works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change to using a `PlaceHolder` instead of an `Image`

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="imgPlaceholder" runat="server" />
</ItemTemplate>
```

Then add your Image to this in the DataBound event.

```
Image myImage = (Image)e.Item.DataItem;
PlaceHolder imgPlaceholder = (PlaceHolder)e.Item.FindControl("imgPlaceholder");
imgPlaceholder.Controls.Add(myImage);
```

The reason you cannot do it the way that you are attempting, is because you are basically saying that the `imgButton` is now a newly created image control, and not the one in the Repeater. What you are thinking you are doing is basically taking all the properties of that `myImage`

Comment: Haha, of course, now it makes perfect sense. Thanks for explaining!

Answer (score 0):

Create and bind list<string> to repeater. Each string in list is the URL to image. Change repeater markup as follows-->

```
<asp:Image ID="imgButton" runat="server" ImageUrl="DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem)" />
```

Comment: As stated in the question, binding a `List<String>` wont be enought in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The following code should work for you:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repButtons" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="repButtons_OnItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Image ID="imgButton" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("ImageUrl") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

---

Make the list of images

```
List<System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image> myButtons = new List<System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image>();

Image myEditButton = new Image();
myEditButton.ImageUrl = "~/images/themes/pencil.png";

myButtons.Add(myEditButton);

repButtons.DataSource = myButtons;
repButtons.DataBind();
```

---